How to use Android MediaCodec to decode an aac audio file
I am using Android MediaCodec to decode an audio file formated in AAC.But the alway output a 0 bytes decodeFile. I have debuged my code, then i found outputBuffer?.remaining() ?: 0 always returns 0.
Could you help me? thanks!
 fun decode() {
        val decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AAC)
        val format =
            MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AAC, sampleRate, 1)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 10000)
        decoder.configure(
            format,
            null,
            null,
            0
        )
        launchWithVM({ // launch a coroutin using viewModelScope
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val contentResolver = getApplication<Application>().contentResolver
                val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, "decodeFile")
                }
                val decodeUri =
                    contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
                if (decodeUri != null) {
                    decoder.start()
                    val fileInputUri = findEncodeFile("encodeFile")
                    val fileInput = contentResolver.openInputStream(fileInputUri!!)
                    val fileOutput = contentResolver.openOutputStream(decodeUri)
                    val bufferSize =
                        decoder.inputFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE)
                    val tmpBuffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
                    var readCount = 0
                    while (readCount >= 0) {
                        val dequeueBufferIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(aSecond) // aSecond is -1L
                        if (dequeueBufferIndex >= 0) {
                            val inputBuffer = decoder.getInputBuffer(dequeueBufferIndex)
                            readCount = fileInput?.read(tmpBuffer)!!
                            inputBuffer?.put(tmpBuffer)
                            val flag = if (readCount < bufferSize) {
                                BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM
                            } else {
                                0
                            }
                            decoder.queueInputBuffer(dequeueBufferIndex, 0, bufferSize, System.currentTimeMillis(), flag)
                        }
                        val buffer = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()
                        val outputBufferId = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(buffer, aSecond)
                        if (outputBufferId >= 0) {
                            val outputBuffer = decoder.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferId)
                            val remain = outputBuffer?.remaining() ?: 0 //remaining is always 0 
                            val outPutBuffer = ByteArray(remain)
                            outputBuffer?.get(outPutBuffer, 0, remain)
                            fileOutput?.write(outPutBuffer, 0, remain)
                            decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(
                                outputBufferId,
                                System.currentTimeMillis()
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    fileInput?.close()
                    fileOutput?.close()
                    decoder.stop()
                }
            }
        }) {
            it.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

Why the code always outputs a 0 bytes file?

Do you have a sample file to share?

Do you mean the audio file or code file? How can i send sample file to you?

A sample of the type of file you're trying to decode. You don't have to send it to me, you can link to sample files on the web.

https://github.com/prettygirl20231/audio
This is url. Thank you!

I suspect that bufferSize is 0, because KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE wasn't specified when configuring the decoder.
Why not use the MediaExtractor class for reading the file? It handles data block sizes automatically. The documentation has some sample code.
